# How do I install skgstat?

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to install skgstat so that I can do a cross-variogram on the Iris dataset. I have ran `pip install scikit-gstat` in the command prompt and it says that it was installed successfully. Although, when I try to run `from skgstat import Variogram` in Jupyter Notebook I get a module not found error.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your kernel?

Answer (score 2):

After command "import", the name of the library should be abbreviated: "skgstat":

```
import skgstat
```